# Lines do not progress on Flot graph using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I want to do a line graph with live data pulled from Ajax. On the Y axis is float data with one digit after the decimal point. On the X axis is a formatted timestamp, preferably "%H:%M:%S.

The following non-Ajax example works fine:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="legendcontainer" style="width: 1000px;position:"></div>
        <div id="placeholder" style="width:1000px;height:400px;"></div>
        <div id="legend" style="width:600px;height:300px;"> </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var DataSet1 = [ [1341354816000, 1.1], [ 1341358185000, 2.2] , [ 1341361620000, 3.3] ];  
            var DataSet2 =[[1341354816000, 5.1], [ 1341358185000, 6.2] , [ 1341361620000, 7.3] ]

            var datasets =
            {
                "DataSet1" :{ label : "DataSet1", data: DataSet1 }, 
                "DataSet2" :{ label: "DataSet2", data: DataSet2 }
            };

            var firstTime =true;
            function plotByChoice(doAll)
            {    
                data = [];
                if (doAll != null)
                {
                    $.each(datasets, function(key, val) 
                    {
                        data.push(val);
                    });
                }   
                else
                {
                    $('#legend .legendCB').each(
                        function(){


                            if (this.checked)
                            {         

                                 data.push(datasets[this.id]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 data.push({label: this.id, data: []})
                            }        
                        }
                    );
                }        

                $.plot($("#placeholder"),data, { series: 
                        {
                            lines: 
                            {
                                show: true,
                            },
                            points: 
                            {
                                show: true
                            }
                        },
                        xaxis: {mode: "time" }, 
                        yaxis: { tickDecimals: 1 },
                        yaxes: [ { min: 0 }, 
                        {
                          alignTicksWithAxis: "right",
                          position: "right",
                          min :-25,
                          max:50                          
                        } ]
            });        
        }

        plotByChoice(this);   
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Next, a modified version using Ajax which does not work. Note that the labels are user-defined and the total number of datasets is variable. There will be only one point per dataset. There is no JavaScript error displayed in the Error Console, there is nothing displayed on the graph and in Firebug I can see the data was fetched once (but only once, with the setInterval I was expecting once every 3 seconds).

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="legendcontainer" style="width: 1000px;position:"></div>
        <div id="placeholder" style="width:1000px;height:400px;"></div>
        <div id="legend" style="width:600px;height:300px;"> </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var datasets = {};  
            var firstTime =true;
            function plotByChoice(doAll)
            {       
                $.ajax({
                url: "graphlist.php",
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function (data) {
                    datasets = $.parseJSON(data);}
                }); 

                data = [];
                if (doAll != null)
                {
                    $.each(datasets, function(key, val) 
                    {
                        data.push(val);
                    });
                }   
                else
                {
                    $('#legend .legendCB').each(
                        function(){

                            if (this.checked)
                            {                                   
                                 data.push(datasets[this.id]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 data.push({label: this.id, data: []})
                            }        
                        }
                    );
                }        

                $.plot($("#placeholder"),data, { series: 
                        {
                            lines: 
                            {
                                show: true,
                            },
                            points: 
                            {
                                show: true
                            }
                        },
                        xaxis: {mode: "time" }, 
                        yaxis: { tickDecimals: 1 },
                        yaxes: [ { min: 0 }, 
                        {
                          alignTicksWithAxis: "right",
                          position: "right",
                          min :-25,
                          max:50                          
                        } ]
            });        
        }

        setInterval(plotByChoice(this), 3000);
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Sample datasets received:

```
    [
    {
        "label": "s#2 ch#1 (ch un)",    "data": [[1422263853,22.7]]
    }
    ,
    {
        "label": "s#2 ch#2 (2_ch2)",    "data": [[1422263853,21.9]]
    }
    ,
    {
        "label": "s#2 ch#3 (N/A)",  "data": [[1422263853,21.7]]
    }
    ]
```

Thank you very much for any assistance, I already spent a frustrating day on this.

Best regards,
Bertrand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, any code you expect to execute after the `ajax` call completes **must** be in the success handler.  Remember the ajax call is `async`, so:

```
...
success: function (data) {
    datasets = $.parseJSON(data);
  }
}); 

// This part executes before the AJAX call completes
data = [];
if (doAll != null)
....
```

You need to do something like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    datasets = $.parseJSON(data);
    drawPlot(datasets);
  }
});

function drawPlot(datasets){
  data = [];
  if (doAll != null) {
...
```

**Second**, you shouldn't mix a `setInterval` with an AJAX calls.  Since you don't know when the `async` call will complete, the timing can not be guaranteed and you'll wind up with multiple AJAX calls happening at once.

```
// again this is called in the success handler
function drawPlot(datasets){
...
  setTimeout(function(){
    plotByChoice(true)
  }, 3000); //<-- ajax success is done, now wait 3 seconds and call again
}
```

Here's [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PjQrY0fSfx9pVmdqnUuM?p=preview) fixing it all up.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, your explanations were helpful but your example did not work. I could see the Ajax calls were working in Firebug, but  the graph simply displayed one set of points and that was it.

As soon as I made the array variable data global, it started working. The points started accumulating, however no lines and no time shown under the X axis. I researched a bit and multiplied the Linux UTC timestamp sent by 1000 to change microsecond to JavaScript millisecond.

It still is not working right yet:

1) There are no lines between the points;
2) The legend keeps getting repeated;
3) The graph should keep moving left instead of bunching up, for example there should be only have 10 points shown per series at a time and the points belonging to the earliest timestamp removed every Ajax call iteration.

I'm pretty sure this will be useful to others, so here is the complete modified listing that sort of works. Any additional help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script data-require="jquery@1.11.0" data-semver="1.11.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="legendcontainer" style="width: 1000px;position:"></div>
        <div id="placeholder" style="width:1000px;height:400px;"></div>
        <div id="legend" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var datasets = {};
            var firstTime = true;
            var data = [];

            function plotByChoice(doAll) 
            {
              $.ajax({
                url: "graphlist.php",
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) 
                {
                  datasets = $.parseJSON(data);
                  drawPlot(datasets);
                }
              });

              function drawPlot(datasets)
              {
                if (doAll != null) 
                {
                  $.each(datasets, function(key, val) 
                  {
                    data.push(val);
                  });
                } 
                else 
                {
                  $('#legend .legendCB').each(
                    function() 
                    {     
                      if (this.checked) 
                      {
                        data.push(datasets[this.id]);
                      } 
                      else 
                      {
                        data.push({
                          label: this.id,
                          data: []
                        })
                      }
                    }
                  );
                }

                $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
                  series: {
                    lines: {
                      show: true
                    },
                    points: {
                      show: true
                    }
                  },
                  xaxis: {
                    mode: "time", minTickSize: [1, "second"], timeformat: "%H:%M:%S"
                  },
                  yaxis: {
                    tickDecimals: 1
                  },
                  yaxes: [{
                    min: 0
                  }, {
                    alignTicksWithAxis: "right",
                    position: "right",
                    min: -25,
                    max: 50
                  }]
                });
              }

              setTimeout(function()
              {
                  plotByChoice(true)
              }, 3000);
            }

            plotByChoice(this);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The JSON data received now looks like this:

```
    [
    {
        "label": "s#2 ch#1 (ch un)",    "data": [[1422349909000,22.8]]
    }
    ,
    {
        "label": "s#2 ch#2 (2_ch2)",    "data": [[1422349909000,22.1]]
    }
    ,
    {
        "label": "s#2 ch#3 (N/A)",  "data": [[1422349909000,22.1]]
    }
    ]
```

Best regards and thanks again! 
Bertrand

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Mark's answer was correct. What needed to be modified was the back end.

Instead of returning one point per series, it keeps in memory the last n points and returns n points at a time.

The JSON can be stored in a session variable. To clear the graph, unset the session variable.

To add points to a series, justn some quick string parsing does the trick:

(PHP code)
        /* concatenate a complete $item prior here in case this series does not exist yet */

```
    $mycharray = explode("\n", $_SESSION['JSON_STRUCTURE']);

    $_SESSION['JSON_STRUCTURE'] = "";

    $found = 0;
    $num = count($mycharray);

    for ($loop = 0; $loop < $num; ++$loop) 
    {
        $mycharray[$loop] .= "\n";                      

        if(InStr($mycharray[$loop], $mylabel) == -1)
        {
            $_SESSION['JSON_STRUCTURE'] .= $mycharray[$loop];
        }
        else
        {
            $found = 1;
            // str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject)
            $new = str_replace( "]\n", ",[" . $date . "," . $mytemperature . "]]\n", $mycharray[$loop]);
            $_SESSION['JSON_STRUCTURE'] .= $new;
        } 
    } 

    if($found == 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['JSON_STRUCTURE'] .= $item;
    }

    echo $_SESSION['JSON_STRUCTURE'];
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Thanks Mark!